# Bitmap image displaying VERY top left corner, not scaling

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to display an image on a [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html), but when I call the `drawBitmap` method, I get only the VERY top left corner, the image doesn't scale to the the screen height and width. Here is my code that involves the custom view:

```
    private class ImageOverlay extends View {

    public ImageOverlay(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getPath(baseImage));
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAlpha(200);

        canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, paint);
        Log.v(TAG, "Drew picture");

        super.onDraw(canvas);           
    }

    private String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if(cursor!=null)
        {
            int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

`baseImage` is a `Uri` object that is passed to my activity and it is **NOT** null! Here is the actual image:
[image: Actual image]
And here is the `Canvas` image:
[image: The canvas image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when I call the drawBitmap method, I get only the VERY top left corner, the image doesn't scale to the the screen height and width.

You're telling your programm to do so: `canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, paint);`
As (0,0) is the top left corner.

If you need a smaller image, you should downscale it, an possibility would be 
`Bitmap small = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);`

Comment: How could I make it the size of the original image, as in the image should look like the first image I posted? I tried Bitmap scaledImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), false); but that gave me the same result as the second picture?

Comment: You have to resize your images width/height to the screens width/height. For example you can get the screen width via: DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); int width = metrics.widthPixels;

Comment: But my image doesn't take up the screen height. I have tried that and it looks too stretched out.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to keep the correct ratio. If your images is supposed to fill out the screens width then you have to set the scaled images height according to that ratio.

Comment: One Example: if you orignal image has Width W and Height H, then you'll have ratio r = W/H. Next you scale down W to w (image width of the scaled down image), now you set h = w/r where h is the image height of the scaled down image. Hope didn't mix up * and /

Answer (score 1):

Use a version of `Canvas.drawBitmap()` which performs the scaling you want, such as [this one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

Btw, your decompressed Bitmap is obviously much larger than you need it to be and it will be taking up a prodigious amount of RAM. I recommend using [`BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) to reduce it.